# Erro de sintaxe Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

Sou iniciante na linguagem `Objective C` e estava praticando, quando recebi alguns erros, segue o código:

```
@interface Pessoas: NSObject
{
int idade;
int peso;
}

-(void) imprimir;
-(void) setIdade: (int) i;
-(void) setPeso: (int) p;

@end

@implementation Pessoas

-(void) imprimir{
    NSLog(@"Meu nome é Lucas, eu tenho %i anos e %i quilos", idade, peso);
}

-(void) setIdade:(int) i{
    idade = i;
}

-(void) setPeso:(int) p{
    peso = p;
}

@end

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]){
    @autoreleasepool {
        Pessoas = lucas;
        lucas = [[Pessoas alloc] init];
        [lucas setIdade:19];
        [lucas setPeso: 66];
        [lucas imprimir];
    }
    return 0;
   }
```

**Lista de Erros:**

> Parse Issue Expected identifier or '('
>   Semantic Issue Use of undeclared identifier 'lucas'
>   Semantic Issue Missing '[' at start of message send expression
>   Semantic Issue Use of undeclared identifier 'lucas' (3x)

Comment: Qual o erro apresentado?

Comment: O primeiro eh: Parse Issue Expected identifier or '('
/
no resto: Semantic Issue - Use of undeclared idenfier 'lucas'

Comment: @LucasCastellani Relate os erros especificamente na pergunta, para que seja mais fácil que os usuário do SOpt possam te ajudar melhor. Qualquer dúvida leia **[Como fazer uma boa pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)** na central de ajuda

Comment: @Caputo Perdão, detalhei os erros na questão.

Comment: @LucasCastellani Não precisa se desculpar, somos uma comunidade e estamos aqui por ajuda mútua.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema está em

```
Pessoas = lucas;
lucas = [[Pessoas alloc] init];
```

Para declarar um objeto, você deve usar a mesma sintaxe usada em C para declarar ponteiros:

```
Pessoas *lucas;
```

A linha acima declara uma variável chamada `lucas` que é um ponteiro para uma instância da classe `Pessoas`, ou seja, `lucas` é um objeto da classe `Pessoas`.

Em geral, costuma-se juntar tudo em uma única linha de definição em vez de uma linha de declaração seguida por uma atribuição. Isto é, em vez de:

```
Pessoas *lucas;
lucas = [[Pessoas alloc] init];
```

é mais comum encontrar:

```
Pessoas *lucas = [[Pessoas alloc] init];
```

Observação: nomes de classes são geralmente no singular. Pense na relação é-um-exemplo-de: `lucas` é um exemplo de `Pessoa` (singular).

Comment: Muito obrigado pela explicação, agora finalmente entendi (;